# ArcGIS Server Error 00178

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3

I'm using Server and Desktop 10.3. I'm trying to publish a geoprocessing tool as a service.This tool is a Python script that extracts raster data, outputs this as csv, and creates a chart in Excel using a VB script. This tool runs perfectly in Desktop. I've registered and validated all of the folders and data referenced in the script on the server. When I try to publsh, I get the error "

> {(u'Data: C:\Website_Test\Python_Scripts\Test_Scripts\Test_Charts\Build_raster_Charts.vbs, used by Script ChartTest cannot be copied to the server', 178): []}

This VB script is contained in of of the folders that has been registered with the server. According to the ESRI help page, the data store entry should cover this, yet it still won't work. Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Comment: Given that Server is 64-bit and platform independent, I wonder if VBScript is supported. I know VBScript is *not* supported on Linux.

Comment: I haven't found any ESRI documentation that says that VB isn't supported.The help page says that .bat, .exe and .dll files can't be copied to the server because of security issues, but that they can be registered in a data store. This is what I've tried to do with the VB scrip

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround. The vbs script is created dynamically inside the Python script tool. I changed the file extension from ".vbs" to ".txt" and I was able to publish the GP service. Once the Python script was on the ArcGIS server, I changed it back to ".vbs"